# Accessing EXIF data

Tags: plone

I'd like to use the EXIF data that comes in the photos that have been uploaded into a gallery. In particular, I like to be able to sort images in a plonetruegallery view of a folder or collection on the EXIF date the photo was taken. Googling tells me that the ATImage type did store the EXIF data, but I haven't seen anything more recently that uses it. Even if I could just get the image import to change the Created date to be that taken from the EXIF DateTimeOriginal then that would be great.

Has anyone else tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ATImage object inherits from imagetransform so they have a method called getExif(): https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/master/Products/ATContentTypes/lib/imagetransform.py#L87

Integration to gallery is up to you and should not be difficult than doing context/getExif in the caption and display the way you want.

The main issue with addons here is about performance and dependencies. Doing parsing with python, store, synchronize, a source of issue that is quite big IMO.

I have already try many python package promize to extract and structure exif without real working out of the box solution.

Answer (score 2):

ATPhoto (http://plone.org/products/atphoto/) is extremely out of date, and you should not use it wholesale, but you could look at how it parses EXIF tags for inspiration (and code-reuse).

Answer (score 2):

for iptc meta data (most image tools store both metadata) you can try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unweb.iptc

it's a slick and modern solution using event-subscribers.
if you only have exif metadata you can re-use the code and do the same using exif-py

Answer (score 1):

As your use case is very narrow it is unlikely others have tried to do the same with Plone. Some general pointers:

Poke the orignal image data stored in ImageField using EXIF-py

https://github.com/ianare/exif-py

Misc. info about Archeypes image and file fields:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/archetypes/files.html